# How to rotate the titles for each subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

folks. Does anyone know how to rotate the title text for several subplots like this:

[image: Rotate image titles or annotations.]

A slight difference between the above images and my desired images is that, each face image in my whole figure was displayed by an individual subplot. And I want to add a rotated title for each subplot figure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A minimal working answer for you. I hope it helps.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=False, figsize=(10,4))

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x)

ax1.plot(x, y)
ax1.set_title('Title 1', y=1.1, rotation = 45) # You can vary y and angle as per choice
ax2.plot(x, 1.5*y)
ax2.set_title('Title 2', y=1.1, rotation = 45)
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your kind help! Your method completely solved my problem.:p

Comment: If you, like me, also want the rotated title to be better aligned, use `ax1.set_title('Title 1', y=1.1, rotation=45, ha='left', va='baseline')`. This mainly occurs when the title to rotate is a long string. (Suggestion based on an answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65400381/5433896.)