# Properly rotate and align annotation labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot-annotations

The following code puts some points on the plane and draws a line from center to each point. For each point, there is a label and want to put the label after the point. Therefore, from center, we see a line, then a point and then a text. I want to put the label with the same slope of the line.

Currently, I have this code, but as you can see the rotated text is not properly aligned. How can I fix that?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from math import *
a = np.array([
[-0.108,0.414],
[0.755,-0.152],
[0.871,-0.039],
],)
labels = ["XXXXXXX", "YYYYYY", "ZZZZZZZ"]

x, y = a.T
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.xlim(-1,1)
plt.ylim(-1,1)

ax = plt.axes()
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
   px = a[i,0]
   py = a[i,1]
   ax.arrow(0, 0, px, py, head_width=0, head_length=0.1, length_includes_head=True)
   angle = degrees(atan(py/px))
   ax.annotate(labels[i], (px, py), rotation=angle)

plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

UPDATE:

I used the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20169686/859227) and modified

```
text_plot_location = np.array([0.51,0.51])
trans_angle = plt.gca().transData.transform_angles(np.array((45,)),text_plot_location.reshape((1,2)))[0]
ax.annotate(labels[i], (px, py), rotation=text_plot_location)
```

However, I get this error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rotate matplotlib annotation to match a line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780198/how-to-rotate-matplotlib-annotation-to-match-a-line)

Comment: That puts the label above the line. In my final code, I have many points and if I put the labels above lines, then the representation will not be good for those line which have small angles.

Comment: I understand, but you should be able to control the offset of the text relative to the line.

Comment: I updated the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not ideal but a bit closer to what you want. The drawback is the arbitrary value of 30 points for the text offset that works for the given labels but needs to be adjusted for longer or shorter labels.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from math import *
a = np.array([[-0.108,0.414],[0.755,-0.152],[0.871,-0.039]])
labels = ["XXXXXXX", "YYYYYY", "ZZZZZZZ"]

x, y = a.T
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.xlim(-1,1)
plt.ylim(-1,1)

ax = plt.axes()
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
   px = a[i,0]
   py = a[i,1]
   ax.arrow(0, 0, px, py, head_width=0, head_length=0.1, length_includes_head=True)
   angle = atan(py/px)
   d = (-1 if px < 0 else 1) * 30
   ax.annotate(labels[i], (px, py), rotation=degrees(angle), textcoords="offset points", 
               xytext=(d*cos(angle), d*sin(angle)), 
               verticalalignment='center', horizontalalignment='center')

plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The link by @mapf is a bit cleaner, but this is what  I came up with:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
a = np.array([
[-0.108,0.414],
[0.755,-0.152],
[0.871,-0.039],
],)
labels = ["XXXXXXX", "YYYYYY", "ZZZZZZZ"]

x, y = a.T

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y)
ax.set_xlim(-1,1)
ax.set_ylim(-1,1)
line, = ax.plot(*a.T)
for jdx, (label, point) in enumerate(zip(labels, a)):
    # find closest point
    tmp = np.linalg.norm(a - point, axis = 1)
    idx = np.argsort(tmp)[1]
    other = a[idx]
    
    # compute angle
    deg = np.angle(complex(*(point - other)))
    deg = np.rad2deg(deg)
    ax.annotate(label, point, rotation = deg,
            ha = 'left', va = 'baseline',
            transform = ax.transData)
ax.grid(True)
fig.show()
```

[image]

I am not sure why the angle does not match the line exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You made a simple mistake in your update. You need to pass `trans_angle` to the `rotation` key word instead of `text_plot_location`, however, I'm not sure if the result is what you are looking for.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from math import *
a = np.array([
[-0.108,0.414],
[0.755,-0.152],
[0.871,-0.039],
],)
labels = ["XXXXXXX", "YYYYYY", "ZZZZZZZ"]

x, y = a.T
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.xlim(-1,1)
plt.ylim(-1,1)

ax = plt.axes()
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    px = a[i, 0]
    py = a[i, 1]
    ax.arrow(0, 0, px, py, head_width=0, head_length=0.1,
             length_includes_head=True)
    text_plot_location = np.array([0.51, 0.51])
    angle = degrees(atan(py / px))
    trans_angle = plt.gca().transData.transform_angles(
        np.array((angle,)), text_plot_location.reshape((1, 2))
    )[0]
    ax.annotate(labels[i], (px, py), rotation=trans_angle)

plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image]